# Finding an SDE satisfied by the stochastic process $X_t=\int_{0}^{t}f(u,t)dW_{u}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am wondering about stochastic processes of the form

$$X_t=\int_{0}^{t}f(u,t)dW_{u}$$

I can't figure out how to convert this into a stochastic differential equation if there were no t dependence on f I could have written 
$$dX_t=f(t) dW_{t} $$
But I don't know how to do it for f(u,t).
What is  the SDE satisfied by this process?

Comment: Look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436824/on-differentiating-a-stochastic-integral-equation). Just to give some intuition suppose that the function $f$ is separable i.e. $f(u,t)=h(u).g(t)$. In this case, we have $X_t = g(t)\int_0^t h(u)dW_u$. Therefore, the differential is simply $dX_t = g'(t)\left(\int_0^t h(u)dW_u\right)dt + g(t)h(t)dW_t$.

Comment: @Sesame Thanks.That answers my question

Comment: @Sesame What about the general case this shows only separable f(u, t) the post you linked to does seem to claim that it is true for any f but I checked and that's not the case. Is there a way to deal with general f?

Comment: My comment intends to give an intuition of what would be the differential formula if $f$ is separable. Could you explain why this won't work for any $f$ ? Of course, you need to assume some regularity on $f$.

Comment: @Sesame I read the book which the op in the post you linked refers to and there was a restriction on G (f in the notation of the post) namely that it be separable besides  if it were that then through integration we should be able to recover this X_t but you can check that it doesn't for general f

Answer (score 0):

First starting from functions of the form

$$f(u, t) =a(u) b(t) $$

$$X_t=b(t) \int_{0}^{t}a(u)dW_{u}$$

Using Ito's product rule ,we get

$$dX_t= (\int_{0}^{t}a(u)b'(t) dW_{u}) dt+(a(t) b(t)) dW_t$$

Equivalently

$$dX_t= (\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial f} {\partial t}
 dW_{u}) dt+f(t, t) dW_t$$

I understand  this much but I am not aware of any method for getting an SDE if the function is not separable.